# XDomainRequest has no content type when sending POST request

Tags: post, content-type, xdomainrequest

I'm working on some cross-domain ajax requests. I use XDomainRequest to send requests in IE8 and IE9. Currently, it works well on Get requests, but not on Post requests.
When I use Fiddle capturing the requests, I find that the Post request has no Content-Type header.
Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it looks like they screwed up and left it out. I am having the same problem.

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) there is no way to set the Content-Type header and I have not found a way myself. You'll see that they actually made it WORSE with a later bug fix. As XDomainRequest is deprecated in IE10 for the correct XMLHttpRequest object using CORS I doubt there will ever be a fix.

If you ever found a way around the problem please post back and let the world know. This is preventing me from using Amazon S3 POST for uploading avatars.

Comment: What's curious to me is that [Microsoft states](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) "Only text/plain is supported for the request's Content-Type header". But that is not how it actually works. Instead, there is simply no Content-Type header at all. You can see this noted in the comments on that post. This actually matters in my situation, as I'm working with an API that will reject any request without a content-type header.